# Boy in a toilet talking to an evil insect-like creature

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I watched a movie approx 5/6 years ago on TV and I don't remember its name and watched it only for 5 minutes. Now I want to watch it in full but do not know its name or any other detail.

I only remember a scene where an adult (young) boy in a toilet talking to an evil insect-like creature (insect is in wash-basin) is standing against him. The insect is using abusive language and then it somehow kills an old man sitting on a pot. Then the adult boy's ear is staring to ejaculate fluid and then he forcibly tried to clear his ear and a long creepy snake like dead thing come out of his ear.

One more thing this insect like thing have some supernatural power and it is long thick insect like a small snake structure but too fatty.

It is like some kind of horror flick and its looks like some recent movie of that time. Can anybody recognize it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like the excellent [**Brain Damage**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094793/combined).

Here's an image from the bathroom scene:

[image]

and here's the "creepy snake" from his ear (it's not a snake): [**NSFW - Gore**](http://rue-morgue.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/bdcolor65.jpg)

Comment: Ah hell - Brain Damage! I should have remembered that classic :) Saw it in a double-bill with Basket Case. Doesn't the parasite sing 'Elmer's Tune'?

Comment: Yep! Snicker. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWpZz5WF4TE

Answer (score 5):

This sounds a bit like *[Naked Lunch](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102511/)*.

From one of the user reviews:

> It's a ride, a drug-induced nightmare full of horribly funny visions (the sort of visions that artists used centuries ago to represent hell). Anuses talk. Aliens sip alcohol in bars. People get impaled. Typewriters turn into bugs. Liquids ooze.

Comment: Sounds like a movie I should see! Added to my list!

Comment: i checked its trailer but its not the movie , even its hero is not young, he is too old as compare to my movie. And i am talking about a horror movie not comedy.

Comment: OK - I'll keep thinking. And contrary to the trailer, Naked Lunch is more horror than comedy, after all, it was directed by David Cronenburg :)

Comment: @Nobby ok but naked lunch is looking older movie and the movie i am talking about is not that old anyways thanx.

Comment: *Naked Lunch* is **not** a comedy. The idea of someone thinking it's funny is a bit disturbing, actually.